# Can't receive response with 503 error (Service Unavailable) in aws-sdk(node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, response, http-status-code-503, aws-sdk

## app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var express_namespace = require('express-namespace');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var e_logger = require('morgan');
var logger = require('./logger.js').getLogger('framework');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var awsControl = require('./routes/awsControl')

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new aws.EC2();

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if ('development' == env) {

    app.set('port', 80);

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(e_logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', routes);
}

// routes
app.namespace('/', function () {
    app.get('describeInstances', awsControl.describeInstances);

});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404
    logger.error(err);
    next(err);
});
```

## awsControl.js

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk'); 
var util = require('util');

aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "myKey",
    secretAccessKey: "mySecretKey",
    region: "ap-northeast-1"
});
console.log("config = " + util.inspect(aws.config));

var ec2 = new aws.EC2({ region: "ap-northeast-1" });

var app01 = 'aaaaaaaa';
var DB01 = 'bbbbbbbb';


exports.describeInstances = function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        Filters: [{
                Name: 'vpc-id',
                Values: ['vpc-cccccccc']
            }],
        DryRun: false
    };

    ec2.describeInstances(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) { // an error occurred
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else { // successful response
            console.log(data);
        }  
    });
}
```

## control.js

```
var Control = function () {
    this.initializePage();
};

Control.prototype = new Object();

Control.prototype = {
    initializePage : function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "describeInstances", 
            success : function (data, status, jQxhr) {

                console.log("### describeInstances success");
                console.log(data);

            },
            error : function (jQxhr, status, error) {
                console.log("### describeInstances error");
                console.log(error);
                console.log(jQxhr);
            },
            complete : function (jQxhr, status) {
                console.log("### describeInstances complete");
                console.log(jQxhr);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I programmed like above and the node web server is operating well.
awsControl.js is server-side javascript and control.js is client-side javascript.
When I connect to my web server, Control class is called first.

Here is the trouble. When I send request with startInstance (AWS-SDK API), it's working in server-side.
However, I can't receive response with 503 error(service unavailable).
On client-side, I always receive error callback with 503 error.
I don't know why I can't receive response.
I set security groups(EC2) and NACL(VPC) up so I don't think that it's firewall trouble.
Is there anybody can tell me how I can find the solution out?

Comment: I'm with the same problem =/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this.

```
ec2.describeInstances(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) { // an error occurred
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else { // successful response
            console.log(data);
            res.send(data); <-- this line
        }  
    });
```

I added just a line I focus to awsControl.js file, then done.